# Obtain node number n of a linked list

Tags: c

If I have a linked list:

```
first node -----> second node ------> third node ---> ?
```

Can I show the third node value ( for example ) without use a classic list-linear-searching algorithm?

My attempt of getting the n'th node:

```
struct node* indexof( struct node* head, int i )
{
    int offset = (int)((char*)head->next - (char*)head);
    return ((struct node*)((char*)head + offset * i));
}
```

Comment: The problem with your function is that the nodes may not be next to each other in memory. This means that using offsets won't work.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your exact linked list implementation, but in general, no.  You will have to traverse the list in order to access the nth element.

This is a characteristic of linked lists, in the sense that the normal tricks you could use for computing an offset into an array or other sequence-like structure will not work, as your individual list elements are not guaranteed to be laid out in memory in any sensible way, so you are forced to follow the `next` pointers in-order to retrieve the third element.

You could consider other data structures that provide constant-time indexed access into your linked list.

Comment: I have implemented a function, but I don't know if it's correct. `struct node*
indexof( struct node* head, int i )
{
        int offset = (int)((char*)head->next - (char*)head);
 
        return ((struct node*)((char*)head + offset * i));
}`

Comment: If my reading of that is correct, then you are relying on your linked list to end up laid out in memory sequentially.  This is *not* a property you can rely upon in general.  If it works sometimes, it's entirely by chance.

Comment: If you have a double-linked-list, you could walk through once to build a list of pointers to power-of-two nodes. Once you have those, you can do much faster binary searches. The linear cost at the beginning might be worth it if you plan to do many searches to a "read-only" data structure. But Gian's recommendation to pick a different data structure is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've picked the wrong data structure. If you want to go straight to nth then you should use an array.

Failing that, what's so bad about going through in linear fashion? Would have to be called a lot on a very long linked list to be causing performance problem.

Comment: It's worth noting that an array is rarely a drop-in replacement for a linked list, in the sense that the cost of resizing a (fixed-size) array tends to be greater than adding a single element to a linked list.  There are other, more appropriate, replacements than just 'an array'.

Answer (score 0):

One of the purposes of a linked list is to be able to easily add and delete nodes with little cost.

You can renounce that capability and use an array of payload pointers, but then *it is no longer a linked list* (what would the purpose be of having a pointer to the next node when the same node can be obtained trivially by arithmetic increment?).

E.g. instead of

```
struct
{
    struct node *next;
    void *payload;
    ...
} node;

node *root = NULL;
```

and allocate space for *no* nodes, you can have

```
typedef struct
{
    void *payload;
    ...
} node;
node *vector = NULL;
size_t vectorsize = 0;
```

and allocate space for as many nodes as initially required, then using `realloc` to extend the list when needed, and `memmove` to  remove nodes by shifting back the nodes beyond the deleted one. This incurs a clear performance loss when adding or removing nodes. On the other hand, the n-th node is just `vector[n]`.

I repeat, *this is no longer a linked list*: it may be that whatever you're needing this for, it can be better accomplished with an array of pointers instead than a linked list.

Which reminds me, you'd do well to explain *why* you need the direct-addressing ability ("State the problem, don't ask how to implement the solution"): it may also well be that what you need is **neither** an array nor a linked list, but, who knows?, maybe a ring buffer, a stack, a hill, or a binary tree.

In some implementations you can even deploy *two* bonded structures, e.g. you might use a (doubly?) linked list in a first phase with lots of insertions and deletions especially of recently inserted data; then you build, and switch to, a pointer array for a second phase where you need direct addressing driven by the node number (use the array as "cache" of list node addresses):

```
for (listsize = 0, scan = root; scan; scan = scan->next)
    listsize++;
if (NULL == (vector = (node *)malloc(listsize * sizeof(node))))
{
    // out of memory
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
for (listsize = 0, scan = root; scan; scan = scan->next)
    vector[listsize++] = scan;
// Now vector[i]->payload is the payload of the i-th node
```